# Convert an array to eloquent model in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have mysql table 'test' with three columns,

```
1.sno    2.name    4.country
```

this code is easily understandable

```
$person = \App\Test::find(1);
$person->country;         //Defined in Test eloquent model
```

now i want to do something like this:

```
$p = ['sno' => 1, 'name' => 'Joe', 'country' => '1' ];
$p->country;      //Return relevent column form countries table as defined in Model
```

The thing to remember is that the user i am trying to map is already present in the database table. How to i convert an array to eloquent model?

Comment: You can use the Model's `fill()` method to convert that array to a populated model

Comment: i am not trying to populate, i am trying to map...

Comment: could u please give me some example

Comment: [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) and [Laravel API Docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill)

Comment: thank you for ur help,, but documentation says "You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. " but i dont want to create... just map. ur help will be appriciated

Comment: So do you want to retrieve the $person, or do you simpy magically want Laravel to guess what country you want to get in your $p array when using object syntax?

Comment: If you've already got a $person record retrieved from the database, what relation do you have defined between person and country in that model?

Comment: yes... i want simply to use the array $p as any other eloquent model... so far what i have done is $p = collect($p); and converted it to a collection. I dont know what to do next.

Comment: the relation works fine when i do $person = \App\Test::find(1);
$person->country; but i want to use the $p same way with existing records

Comment: So if your `$p` is a Collection, and you have a a`country` relation defined; just "lazy eager load" the country model through the relation: `$p->load('country');` [Laravel docs on Lazy Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

Comment: BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method load does not exist. REASON: its just a collection not eloquent object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could instantiate the model class with no attributes:

```
$dummy = new \App\Test;
```

Then you can call the `newInstance()` method:

```
$attributes = ['sno' => 1, 'name' => 'Joe', 'country' => '1' ];
$desiredResult = $dummy->newInstance($attributes, true);
```

The `true` flag in the method is telling eloquent that the instance already exists in database, so you can continue working with it normally. Now you can do:

```
$desiredResult->country //'1'
```

Comment: and what if i have an array containing multiple $attributes (Array of Arrays). How will I instantiate them all without iteration so i may be able to do like this $desiredResult->firstI()->country;